# Dynamic Table rows not displaying in correct sequence in DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html-table

```
 success: function (data, status) {
            var header = $("#MainDiv");

            header.html(null);
            var headertemplate = $("<table class='searchlistbody'><tr></th><th>Name</th></tr>");
            header.append(headertemplate);

            $.each(data, function () {
                var template = $("<tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'><span class='searchListTitle'></span></td></tr>");

                        template.find('span.searchListTitle').attr('title', this.Title);

                // add the template to the collection
                header.append(template);
            });
            header.append("</table>");
        },
```

Now when I was trying to set the border on the table I noticed that it was only applying border on th tags i.e. Header (Name).

```
 Debugging further in fire bug I saw that the DOM sequence is in this format
        <table class='searchlistbody'><tr><th>Name</th></tr></table>
        <tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'>Test</td></tr>
        <tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'>Test</td></tr>
        <tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'>Test</td></tr>
        <tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'>Test</td></tr>
        <tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'>Test</td></tr>
```

Can anyone please tell me why is the table closing before appending all the for loop rows....Its an AJAX Call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add elements in pieced to the dom. So you add a table to header, then you append rows to the table

```
 success: function (data, status) {
            var header = $("#MainDiv");

            header.html(null);
            var headertemplate = $("<table class='searchlistbody'><tr></th><th>Name</th></tr></table>");
            header.append(headertemplate);

            $.each(data, function () {
                var template = $("<tr> <td class='campnameAltrow'><span class='searchListTitle'></span></td></tr>");

                        template.find('span.searchListTitle').attr('title', this.Title);

                // add the template to the collection
                headertemplate.append(template);
            });
        },
```

Comment: Manipulating DOM has very inconsistent behaviors,,,,can you please point me to some good article or any book which can help me learn better .... @Musa

Answer (score 1):

judging from the documentation of append function: http://api.jquery.com/append/ it actually tries to work with proper DOM elements

do NOT try to use it as *string concatenation* operation

instead try creating your table element and appending TH and TRs there separately:

```
var table = $("<table ...></table>")
table.append("<th>...</th>")
$.each(function() {
  ...
  table.append("<tr>...</tr>")
  ...
})
```